# How to install an application (setup.exe) using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to install an application which is build using install shield (Setup.exe). The installation process contains two dialogs to proceed with. installation begins the FTDI CDM Drivers and then proceed with the actual application. The requirement is the installation to be automated using pywinauto. Problem is How to detect to the dialogs dynamically when installation is running with the setup process without manual intervention. I used os.system() to invoke the setup.exe but could not get hold of the dialogs poping within it.

I using ver3.5.2 of python 64 bit

```
import pywinauto, time, os
from pywinauto.application import Application
sv = os.system("C:\Python_Samples\AutomationScripts\Release_Setup.exe")
app = Application().Connect(title=u'FTDI CDM Drivers', class_name='#32770')
window = app.Dialog
button = window.Button2
button.SetFocus()
button.Click()
```

Comment: Can you post the code as text? And please provide the link to FTDI driver package. Not sure pywinauto is really needed. It should be simpler without GUI.

Comment: As said, i m trying to install an install shield generated package, which should be installed without the user clicking the next button. the driver package is also a part of the package itself.

Comment: I need the download link to reproduce exactly the same on my side (is it D2XX or D3XX or VCP???). Can you edit your answer with the code? It looks ugly in a comment. This is needed for fast copy-paste.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit - this is also important info.

Comment: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm. There is no direct link pointing to the setup. Please scroll down and download the version 2.12.26  64 bit  for windows.

Comment: this driver setup was included as a pre-requestie with in my Release_setup.exe. everytime i run the release setup, i want the driver installation without user intervention using python

Answer (score 0):

To install this driver without pywinauto you need `devcon.exe` utility (can be easily googled to download) with command: `devcon.exe install ftdibus.inf <hw_id>` where hw_id is a "Hardware Id" property from device properties in Device Manager (manually right click on "Properties" for the device, go to second tab and choose "Hardware Ids" combo box item).

The dialog you're trying to detect is probably the confirmation dialog to trust this manufacturer. Usually it can be automated by `certutil` command if you have certificate file to add to the Root Certificate storage on the PC. But D2XX driver comes without certificate file, so you have to detect this dialog by pywinauto.

It can be done so:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

popup_dialog = Desktop(backend="win32").window(title="Some title")
# wait up to 10 seconds, return False if timed out
if popup_dialog.exists(timeout=10):
    popup_dialog.Trust.click() # or maybe .click_input()
    popup_dialog.wait_not('visible') # make sure it's gone (raise exception otherwise)
```